# Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application' Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jitpack

I want publish a simple library in jitpack. I create an Android project and add new Android library module and push project to github. Edit build.gradle library module like this

[image]

and add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to root build.gradle

But I get error. Log is:

```
Build starting...
Start: Sun Aug 22 05:14:22 UTC 2021 d352f549d622
Git:
1.0.0-0-g9e976ac
commit 9e976acd32d4b2d1b3b645779f2b72b1450c9f0e
Author: alireza 
Date:   Sun Aug 22 09:40:19 2021 +0430

    Initial commit


Found Android manifest
Android SDK version: . Build tools: 
Found gradle
Gradle build script
Found gradle version: 7.0.2.
Using gradle wrapper
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
.10%.20%.30%.40%.50%.60%.70%.80%.90%.100%

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.0.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-05-14 12:02:31 UTC
Revision:     1ef1b260d39daacbf9357f9d8594a8a743e2152e

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_252 (Private Build 25.252-b09)
OS:           Linux 3.16.0-10-amd64 amd64

0m5.588s
Getting tasks: ./gradlew tasks --all
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jitpack/build/app/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
Tasks: 

WARNING:
Gradle 'install' task not found. Please add the 'maven' or 'android-maven' plugin.
See the documentation and examples: https://jitpack.io/docs/

Adding maven plugin
Found android library build file in mytoastlibrary
Running: ./gradlew clean -Pgroup=com.github.shojaeialireza -Pversion=1.0.0 install
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

> Configure project :
Gradle version Gradle 7.0.2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jitpack/build/app/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
2021-08-22T05:15:11.863645465Z
Exit code: 0

ERROR: No build artifacts found
```

JDK version is 11 in android studio setting.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: Yes, I found solution

Comment: The one with `jitpack.yml`, right? By telling Jitpack to use JDK 11.

Comment: @Alireza what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**I faced the same issue , I fixed it by following things:**

1. I updated java in my system to JAVA 11 , updated build.gradle and Gradle in settings preference.

compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

kotlinOptions {
jvmTarget = '11' }

[image]

2. Create `jitpack.yml` file in root folder of your project

   jdk:

   - openjdk11
     before_install:
   - ./scripts/prepareJitpackEnvironment.sh

[image]